# How to pipe output audio to gstreamer script?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

iam working on a small project where i play music over bluetooth to my Raspberry pi. Also i would like to analyse the audio too.

How can i pipe the Raspberry pi audio output to a gstreamer c script? I got a correctly working solution with an mp3 file, but ofc i would like to expand this to read audio output from my RPi.

Here is the source i used in my gstreamer script to read from a file:

```
data.source = gst_element_factory_make ("uridecodebin", "source");
g_object_set (data.source, "uri", "file:///home/pi/example.mp3", NULL);
```

Do i need to loopback the audio to the microphone jack and use this as a source? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: C is not a scripting language. And that is not a valid C source code.

Comment: forgive me my wrong use of words. The provided code is valid, when using the gstreamer library

Comment: The code as such is not a valid compilation unit! You want to read [ask].

Comment: what do you want? Should i post the whole code? The FAQ even told me to not copy the whole code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the RPi. Assuming it runs a regular linux chances are high that the sound output is done via PulseAudio. for each output device PulseAudio also offers a "monitor" device fir this output. This one can be used to capture audio data.

These monitor devices may be made visible by some system configuration - but I'm not sure. Maybe they exist by default.

From a GStreamer point of view you would use the "pulsesrc" element to capture audio:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-pulsesrc.html

From there your regular GStreamer functions apply - meaning you could write the data to disk, make live analysis of the data etc.. Since this can be quite complex its hard to give a general advice..